# SceneKit positioning of the node

Tags: swift, swift2, scenekit

I have two SCNNodes which have a geometry type set to SCNBox.

```
let node1 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 0.0))
let node2 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 20.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 0.0))

node1.position.x = 0.0
node2.position.x = 10.0

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node1)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node2)
```

When I look at my scene then the nodes are overlapping, however they should not, or should they? I don't manipulate camera at the same time. For now I don't have any physics field set.

When I print the following:

```
node1.presentationNode.position.x
node2.presentationNode.position.x
```

or

```
(node1.geometry as! SCNBox).width
(node2.geometry as! SCNBox).width
```

Then the values that are printed as the same as the ones that were initially set.
Is the anchor point of the node by default the left down corner?
The strange thing is that when I move the node in touchesBegan/touchesEnded and position it at the same position then the nodes don't overlapp.
How to place nodes of the SceneKit correctly?

Comment: What event has happened when you see the difference in separation? Is this happening when you manipulate the camera?

Comment: Please take a look at my edits. In the example code above the nodes are always overlapping. However when I move the node in touchesBegan and place it at exactly the same position then they don't overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for help.
I found the solution.
Nodes are positioned based on the anchor point which is in the middle of the node's width.

Comment: Please mark your answer as Accepted so that the question will show as closed/answered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting your axis mixed up. The width of node2 is 20, but you are only moving node1 (width of 10) by 10. Try moving it by 20 (or 23 for a small gap).

Comment: I am moving the node2 by 10 and width of the node1=10.